# Proper conjugation of "to wit."

Tags: verbs, conjugation

Obviously, *wot* is the present tense, and *wist* is the preterite, but what is the auxiliary form of this verb? I have always assumed it to be *wist,* so I have always said, *... have/had wist,* but I am unsure of if this is correct. I checked Wiktionary and they included no mention of the auxiliary form. I checked another website and it clearly just used a script to decline English verbs.

I am wondering about this specifically, but I am asking broadly.

Comment: I niste why people ask questions without providing the research they've done, so answerers don't have to repeat it

Comment: @green_ideas Name it as a duplicate, then; you show me where it has been asked before. What's more, to my knowledge, *nisten* hasn't been used since the Middle English period, though I suppose there are many Early Modern English texts that use it. But I am referring to Modern and Contemporary English.

Comment: I am not saying the question is a duplicate. Read what I wrote again.

Comment: @MatthewT.Scarbrough Your use of non-standard terms like “auxiliary form” for what presumably is meant to the past participle is somewhat confusing.  You say you checked Wiktionary but it clearly tells you the answer to your question there.

Comment: @tchrist So why is this still open?

Comment: "to woo" (sorry couldn't help it)

Comment: This verb no longer exists in modern English. It is defunct, deceased, gone to join the choir invisible. Whatever made you think otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

**A Original past participle, pre-historical times - c. 1400**

The original past participle of *wit* ‘to know, have knowledge’ – needed to form the perfect as required in the question ‘I have known’ – is ***witen*** (< early Middle English *iwiten* < Old English *gewiten*).

I could not actually retrieve a single quotation of a perfect with *witen*. The only instances I found have prefixes, such as the adversative prefix *at*, meaning something like ‘mis-, fore-.’ It derives the meaning ‘make known to the detriment of someone’ > ‘reproach, blame, accuse’ (cf. German *ver-weissen*). An example is presented in (1).

> (1) þe hule hire **atwiten hadde** // in hwucche stude he sat an gradde,
>   ‘the Owl **had reproached** her // in which stead she sat and sang’
>   ([*The Owl and the Nightingale*, lines 935-6](https://archive.org/stream/owlandnightingal00atkiuoft#page/78/mode/2up), c. 1250)

I did find clear examples of passives though, for instance from a Middle English apocryphal gospel in (2).

> (2) þaire wordes ful wide **sail witen be**
>   ‘their words **shall be known** full widely’
>   ([*Middle English Rhymed Nicodemus*, line 223](https://archive.org/stream/middleenglishha01hulmgoog#page/n122/mode/2up), c. 1340)

There do not seem to be any more clear attestations of *witen* after c. 1400.

**B Reanalysed past participle, c. 1400 - 1900**

Speakers tried to regularise the conjugation of *wit*. In particular, they extended past tense *wist* to the past participle as well. The Oxford English Dictionary remarks,

“[t]he original conjugation, typically represented by *to wit* or *wete* , present *I* and *he wot*, *thou wost*, *we, ye*, and *they wite*, past tense *wist*, past participle *witen*, presented many apparent anomalies, and various attempts at normalization were made by means of analogical formations.”

The reanalysed past participle of *wit* thus became ***wist***.

Early Modern English examples of perfects with *wist* are shown in (3) and (4).

> (3) if i **hadde wist** my letter should haue commen to your graces hands
>   (*Actes and monuments*, 1583)

> (4) this canius aunswered thus: if i **had wist** it, thou **haddest not wist** it
>   (*The works of our ancient*, 1687).

**C Disappearance of the word, c. 1900 - today**

The verb *wit* and all of its forms, including the past participle, are no longer in common use. The word must be regarded as extinct in standard Present-Day English. Educated speakers may be aware of its earlier existence, and hence use it for stylistic effect, e.g., in archaic, anachronistic, jocular or pastiche settings. The expression ‘to wit’ has remained in use, but speakers are not normally aware of its origin as a verb anymore (see e.g., Hot Licks’s comment above, who suggested its function is purely adverbial). But speakers can do whatever they want with their language, so if some people still use the word, then that's perfectly fine of course...

Comment: This shows good research, but OP does not add any historical tags (E-ME; archaisms etc) or any research. Comments 1 & 3 sum up the situation as it stands.

Comment: Well, it seems to me that the only way to explain the past participle of "wit" is by looking at the historical record. Also, the question says, " I am asking broadly."

Answer (score 0):

"To wit" is an [adverb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to%20wit) meaning "namely".  There's nothing to conjugate.

Comment: "To wit," is a verb that means "to know." It's root word is "wītan." Cognate with the German word, "wissen." It's still fairly common.

Comment: @MatthewT.Scarbrough - It hasn't been "common" for hundreds of years.

Comment: I hear it pretty much every day of my life and use it pretty much every day of my life. I would call that common enough to warrant a question.

Comment: @MatthewT.Scarbrough - In which corner of Scotland do you live?

Comment: the boot shaped part, next to Texas, right next to Mississippi. It's just south of Arkansas, and north of the Gulf of Mexico.

Comment: @HotLicks in his own answer, our friend says the word is rare 

Comment: How is it an adverb? Outside of Scotland and parts of the North nigh to the Wall, *to wit* is a defective verb, occurring for most of us only in the infinitive but not especially rare used in that way. In the more septentrional sections of the Isle of Britain and various smaller isles frozen above it, *to wit* still sees normal use as a tensed verb, but it is an odd one like the modals in that it takes no *-s* form and has other peculiarities. Again, non-defective use in present-day speech is now only regional. It is sometimes used ***unwittingly***, as I haven't just now done here. :)

Comment: @tchrist - Consult my link.

Comment: @MatthewT.Scarbrough - So you're saying it's a Cajun/Creole term?

Comment: it's an old verb, which is a preterite-present verb (modal verbs also are preterite-present verbs btw). It still is used in archaic literature and is part of Modern English.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not going to be the best answer, due to how rare the word is today.

Basic internet searches return one example that does attempt to show the verb's declension with have/had, and it simply follows the usual rule of using the simple past tense along with its auxiliary verb.

Present tense, I/You/He/She/It/We/They *wot*

Simple Past, I/You/He/She/It/We/They *wist*

With a helping verb: I/You/He/She/It/We/They have/had *wist*

Just a suggestion.

Comment: you done good, kid. I couldn't of wist a better answer

Comment: this answer is informed by the basic asker-initiated research I referred to an hour ago. look at all that's transpired since then.

Comment: @green_ideas Sometimes, research doesn't cut it. I looked before hand, not because I wasn't sure, but because I wanted a second opinion. I been writing it that way for years now, but I've finally decided to make sure I'm right and not left.

I have learned though, every time I come back here, to treat this place like cancer, because I lose brain cells every time I come back here. (Actually, technically, gain them, under the cancer analogy.) It's a 2 minute Answer. It didn't take me that long to type--I wanted to wait before publishing it.

Comment: the preferred is to stick your research in your question and specify why that isn't satisfactory for you, why it doesn't suffice

Comment: @green_ideas I understand that. Believe me, I do. But what I have learned in years of teaching, and even more in learning, is to never assume the questioner knows how to even search for something extensively. When I was growing up, as you, we were taught what a dictionary is, how to use it, then what the internet is, and how to use it. Children now, aren't taught that. The most receptive method is to give them the answer the first time, explain how it can be found, and the second time to make them look themselves. Sometimes, it may take many times before they gain confidence enough to look.

Comment: from the [Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask): Search, and research
Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"

Comment: I'm afraid this is the wrong answer in that you have a few of the forms wrong. Also, verbs don't have declensions; they have conjugations. See [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wit) and the [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/229569) for how to correctly conjugate this præterite-present verb, a classification which explains its curiosities.